# How can get five star rating data in drupal 6 services views?

Tags: 6, services, rating

i am using drupal 6.x, added five star(fivestar module) rating functionality to a node in my site. 
Everything working fine but i want to users rated data in drupal json services for mobile development, In json services i m getting nodes every data except rating.. so can you please help me. How can i get the users rating data in json services(Services_view module).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Services views](https://drupal.org/project/services_views) module to achieve this,

**Procedure :**

Using services views you will need to add all your required fields on your views.

Step 1: For adding new view navigate to

```
[your-site]/admin/structure/views/add
```

[image]

Step 2: Adding your fields

[image]

You will fetch the resource as below,

```
http://example.com/<endpoint path>/views/<view name>
```

Comment: Thanks @shrish... i m already using services views.. how can i add fields to the view

Comment: sorry, I got it wrong, services entity in only for D7

Comment: I have updated the answer :)

Comment: thanks for your update but i m using drupal 6.26 version, in that there is no structure path in it.

Comment: Navigate to  [your-site]/admin/build/views/add